# How to write a shell script to output the result of a query to a text file

Tags: linux, oracle, shell

I want to write a shell script that will have a SQL select query and will output a text file.

My server is Linux, database is oracle.

I connect to my database by:

```
putty- su - oracle
. .profile_1120_rdbms
sqlplus SYSTEM/SYADM
sql> here i write sql query
```

But i want my query to run from shell script, which run as root user.

I do not know which environments to set /do i need any drivers installed.

I have tried some pieces of code, but they give me `sqlplus not found /invalid command`. I am not able to connect to db.

Please suggest me if there is some other way... I just want to run my sql from some script and have output in some text file.

Comment: What is `putty-`?

Answer (score 0):

You can give sql*plus a script filename with `@file` --

```
sqlplus scott/tiger @query.sql
```

For outputting just the query results, I've used commands like these:

```
set echo off;
set feedback off;
set linesize 100;
set pagesize 0;
set sqlprompt '';
set trimspool on;
spool result.txt;
```

at the beginning to the query.sql file to suppress headings, prompts, etc.

Comment: i want to have shell script. i dont know which environments to set in shell script to get oracle connection.

Comment: There's environment vars like `PATH` and `ORACLE_HOME` that are probably set in your `.profile`